# How to render with sky texture but get transparent background?

Tags: rendering, light

I use sky texture as world as part of my lightning setup. How do I render with transparent background while keeping the light emitted by sky texture?

Comment: Hello :). This thread should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1303/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the render properties under *Film* check the *Transparent* box (for Cycles render engine)